# Не могу вывести id максимальных повторений?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Мне нужно вывести id компании вместе с максимальных смен ее руководителей за дату. Вторую часть я сделал, но у меня не получается чтобы отображался id. Вот запрос

```
select max(total) from (select consolidation_of_the_head.id_subdivision as fak, count(consolidation_of_the_head.nomer) as total from consolidation_of_the_head where consolidation_of_the_head.data between '2002-04-04' and '2022-06-27' group by consolidation_of_the_head.id_subdivision) as result ;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо чтобы было еще и отображение самого id рядом с max.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используя запрос

```
select consolidation_of_the_head.id_subdivision as fak, count(consolidation_of_the_head.nomer) as total from consolidation_of_the_head where consolidation_of_the_head.data between '2002-04-04' and '2022-06-27' group by consolidation_of_the_head.id_subdivision order by count(consolidation_of_the_head.nomer)
```

Comment: ```select consolidation_of_the_head.id_subdivision as fak, count(consolidation_of_the_head.nomer) as total from consolidation_of_the_head where consolidation_of_the_head.data between '2002-04-04' and '2022-06-27' group by consolidation_of_the_head.id_subdivision order by count(consolidation_of_the_head.nomer) limit 1```

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков пробовал также, но лимит делает не совсем правильно, правильный должен быть за этот период 5 и 3. Но запрос выводит 3 и 1, что не верно.

Comment: Понятия не имею что у вас твориться в базе, как указано выше - нужны подробности. ваш запрос 1 в 1 делает тоже самое что и мой только еще и теряет первое поле подзапроса :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я сейчас скрин приложу

Comment: Почитайте правила перед тем как выкладывать скрин, скажу заранее - я его даже смотреть не буду. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , во втором по счету комментарии под вопросом вам написали что нужно и в каком виде :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Хорошо учту

Comment: Как отредактируете - пинганите, укажу где еще у вас ошибка :)